# Sp_whoisactive equivalent in Extended Events

Tags: sql, sql-server, extended-events

So I have been using sp_whoisactive to monitor some activity on my SQL servers and I was wondering how to create some thing similar in extended events. I have a basic understanding of events and have created a few but  I have no idea what values and parameters to monitor in extended events to get the same out put as sp_whoisactive.

Has any one else tried some thing like this before with any luck.